# View stack trace and information of Android application crash

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android app that I've installed on a device via an .apk file. This app is not on the play store or anything. The device and app are used in moving vehicles where I can't connect android studio and logcat up to it to diagnose any crashes. Is there any way I can still view the stack trace or view information about the crashes, just with the device itself?

Comment: Have you tried crash report libraries, like Crashlytics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes with scoop
Scoop catches and saves the stack traces of crashing apps and displays all crashes in a list so you don't have to look through annoyingly long logcat anymore.
Scoop supports both rooted and non-rooted devices (though non-rooted devices require some setup; see the repository wiki for details [here](https://github.com/TacoTheDank/Scoop)).

add permission for read logs for this app:

```
adb shell pm grant xyz.paphonb.scoop android.permission.READ_LOGS
```